# How to install Forge scr 1.6.2

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I recently changed a lot of code within my mod and switched to make it available for Minecraft 1.6.2. However one of the classes is getting an error on that version (*Made originally for 1.5.2 and 1.6.2 - updated using 1.6.4).

I cannot install forge as I keep getting a 403 Forbidden error. I believe Forge changed some file names to `.stash` and that is causing the issues.

I am making this mod available for 1.6.2 as a request from one of its users. not having it available for that version would be a real disappointment as I like to meet everyones required needs.

How to install Forge SCR 1.6.2 (Latest) without getting these errors:
[image]

(I have been trying to do this for 3 days now so I am not coming here to copy past solutions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the latest 1.6.4 version. Minecraft changed the location of their resources and libraries, so Forge is looking in the wrong places now. The last 1.6.4 uses the old install system, but if you want to you can try the new build system called ForgeGradle by using the 2nd to last 1.6.4 version. This would be a good idea as this is the only way for 1.7+.

Good luck!

(P.S. if you want to stick with 1.6.2, you can probably snatch the new locations from the 1.6.4 scripts)